# Different ways of logging in a user without having them to type anything?

Tags: users, 8, rules, actions

I'm on Drupal 8 and currently looking to replicate similar functionality like: https://www.drupal.org/project/urllogin -- They do not have a D8 version yet.

I need to auto login a specific user depending on which URL the user visits. How can this be done on D8? I was thinking of using rules, but there doesnt seem to be an **action** for "login a user" if Path alias equals X.

Another possible scenario I could just do is create a custom module to auto login a user. Which functions would I need to fire in Drupal 8 to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a big security risk.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use drupal_session_regenerate(), you can see the use of this function [here](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!core!includes!session.inc/function/calls/drupal_session_regenerate/8). All you have to do is either play with Uid or if you want to do this for anonymous user then you just create a user xyz and use that ID for session regenerate. You can grab the UID from URL for different users like www.example.com/custom-url-to-login/125 or www.example.com/custom-url-to-login?uid=125

now supposing 125 be the ID of user whom you want to login on visiting the URL.

The code will go something like this:

```
global $user;
$user = user_load(540); // suppose 540 be UID of xyz account
drupal_session_regenerate();
```

This is just a suggestion, if it does not work for you please let me the know the correct solution.

Thanks

Comment: I think that meddling with the global variable $user is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Auto Login URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_login_url) Module

**Use case**

You may get an auto login URL for a user($uid).

```
// Drupal 7.
$auto_login_url = auto_login_url_create($uid, $destination);
print $auto_login_url;

// Drupal 8. As above plus.
$alu_service = \Drupal::service('auto_login_url.create');
auto_login_url = $alu_service->create($uid, $destination);
print $auto_login_url;
```

Or convert all links of a text to auto login for a `user($uid)`.

```
// Drupal 7.
$auto_login_url_text = auto_login_url_convert_text($uid, $text);
print $auto_login_url_text;

// Drupal 8. As above plus.
$alu_service = \Drupal::service('auto_login_url.create');
auto_login_url_text = $alu_service->convert_text($uid, $text);
print $auto_login_url_text;
```

Also there are two tokens:

```
['tokens']['user']['auto-login-url-token']
['tokens']['user']['auto-login-url-account-edit-token']
```